# Does anybody know the keyboard shortcut to open a new terminal tab on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows?

Tags: windows, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I hope you guys are doing well.

Does anybody know the keyboard shortcut to open a new terminal tab on "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows"? I have tried several shortcuts like `ctrl + shift + t` etc... but without success.

I have also tried install `xdotool`. However, when I type `xdotool key ctrl+shift+t`, the output I have is:

`Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance`

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: You are running on a GUI, aren't you? Is the DISPLAY environment variable set to a reasonable value?

Comment: No, actually I just have a black window where I can type commands without any other thing available.

Comment: How then do you expect xdotool to work, if you don't have X running????

Answer (score 2):

Bash doesn't do tabs; that's the terminal emulator's or console manager's job. If you have a console manager that supports multiple tabs then use whatever keyboard shortcut it has for that.

Comment: How can I know?

Comment: If it isn't reasonably obvious from the window decorations then you don't have it.